# How to Convert the powershell script code to python code?

Tags: python, powershell

How can I convert a for loop in Powershell script to python code?

Power shell script

```
 $result = Foreach ($row in $csv)
 {   $row   
 if ($row.Param_Name -eq "p_s3bucket_arn") { $row.Param_Value = $S3Bucketarn }
 }
```

Python Code:

```
   with open('C:/test.csv') as csvfile:
   readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
   for row in readCSV:
      if(row[0]=='p_instance_count'):
        row[1]=len(instance_count)   # expecting to write in csv file as p_instance_count,10
```

Error while Executing Python Code:

> if(row[0]=='p_instance_count'):
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

CSV

```
Param_Name,Param_Value
p_instance_count,
p_tag_name,tag123
```

Comment: list index out of range for row[0] means your row contains nothing. can you add contents of your csv file with the question?

Comment: Improve formatting

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need.

```
data = []
with open('C:/test.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(readCSV)   #skip header
    for row in readCSV:
        if row[0]=='p_instance_count':
            data.append((row[0], len(instance_count)))   
        else:
            data.append((row[0], ""))

with open('C:/test.csv', "w") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

---

Using `csv.DictReader`

**Ex:**

```
data = []
with open('C:/test.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        if row["Param_Name"]=='p_instance_count':
            data.append((row["Param_Name"], len("instance_count")))   
        else:
            data.append((row["Param_Name"], ""))
```

Comment: I am getting if (row[0] == 'p_instance_count'):
IndexError: list index out of range do not know where to change.

Comment: Can you try using `DictReader`